# Adding Example RequestBody in swagger micronaut

Tags: swagger, micronaut

I generated swagger for micronaut using the instructions provided in https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-openapi/latest/guide/index.html

So I have a controller method like:

```
    @Consumes("application/vnd.api+json")
    @Produces("application/vnd.api+json")
    @Post("/{id}/users")
    @RequestBody
    public HttpResponse addAndAssignTarget(@PathVariable("id") Long projectId, @Body @Parameter() JsonNode user) {
```

I am not using a POJO for adding users for another reason which is out of context for this question. Thus, the generated swagger ui shows `{}` as example for request body. I would like to change this to something like. How can I do this?

```
{
    "data" : {
            "type": "projects",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "some-name1",
                "description": "some-description",
                "partner_company": "some-compnay"
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 3):

It looks much better if you use POJO. However, you can add an example as string, but the problem with that if you have any nested objects the quotation marks won't look nice (will be escaped "):

```
@Consumes("application/vnd.api+json")
@Produces("application/vnd.api+json")
@Post("/{id}/users")
@RequestBody
public HttpResponse addAndAssignTarget(@PathVariable("id") Long projectId,
@Body @RequestBody(content = @Content(schema = @Schema(example = "[0, 2, 3]"))) JsonNode user){
```

}

Also it is not a Paramater, but a `@Body` and `@RequestBody` for annotation purposes.

Output will be:

```
"[0, 2, 3]"
```